# Assigning Variables from JSON in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, nested

I've searched across dozens of answers for the last week but I haven't been able to find an example of what I'm trying to do, happy to be pointed to something that I've missed, and I'm new to Python so I apologise if this is something trivial.

I'm trying to read in a configuration from a JSON file so that I can abstract the configuration from the script itself.

I want to be able to assign the configuration value to a variable and perform an action on it, before moving on to the next category in a nested list, of which the categories could change/expand over time (music, pictures, etc).

The JSON file (library.json) currently looks like this:

```
{"media":{
    "tv": [{
        "source": "/tmp/tv",
        "dest": "/tmp/dest"
        }],
    "movies": [{
        "source": "/tmp/movies",
        "dest": "/tmp/dest"
    }]
}}
```

The relevant script looks like this:

```
import json
with open(libfile) as data_file:
data = json.load(data_file)

for k, v in (data['media']['tv']):
    print (k, v)
```

What I was hoping to see as output was:

```
dest /tmp/dest
source /tmp/tv
```

What I am seeing is:

```
dest source
```

It feels like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Apologies in advance, my  upvotes don't count because I am too much of a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works,

```
import json
with open('data.json') as json_file:
  data = json.load(json_file)
  for p in data['media']['tv']:
      dst = (p['dest'])
      src = (p['source'])
      print (src, dst)
```

Comment: Please add more explanation, telling how this would solve the problem and what approach you followed.

Comment: @glen-kennedy I have detailed the answer and make it precise, so there are no confusions

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#how-to-denote-f-strings) and [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) that will aggregate  elements.

```
import json
with open("dummy.json") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for i, j in data["media"].items():
    print(i)
    print("\n".join(f'{str(k)} {str(l)}' for k,l in list(zip(j[0].keys(), j[0].values()))))
    print("\n")
```

Output:

```
tv
source /tmp/tv
dest /tmp/dest


movies
source /tmp/movies
dest /tmp/dest
```

Comment: I assume I'm making a transcription mistake, but I am getting a syntax error on execution with this code:
`with open(libfile) as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
for i, j in data["media"].items():
    print(i)
    print("\n".join(f'{str(k)} {str(l)}' for k,l in list(zip(j[0].keys(), j[0].values()))))
    print("\n")`

Comment: That would be it then, I am running 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `data['media']['tv']` is actually a **list** of dictionaries.

You can tell because it looks like this: `"movies": [{..` (Note the bracket `[`)

That means that instead of this:

```
for k, v in (data['media']['tv']):
    print (k, v)
```

You should be doing this:

```
for dct in (data['media']['tv']):
    for k, v in dct.items():
        print(k, v)
```

Comment: This also worked, which is confusing the crap out of me, because I am sure I tried this before and it threw up errors, but I think I had the items() in the wrong place previously. Thank you.